# Glide into listview

Tags: android, listview, android-glide

I am using Glide to download and show images into listview. The problme is that when I scroll the listview and then I go back, the images changes continuously. They are not downloaded again but they simply change as there is a problem with the recycle of the view. Following there is my code.

```
        storageRef2.getDownloadUrl()
       .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                        .load(uri)
                                        .asBitmap()
                                        .listener(new RequestListener<Uri, Bitmap>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onException(Exception e, Uri model,
                                                                       Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "glide failed " + e.getMessage());
                                                return false;
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Uri model,
                                                                           Target<Bitmap> target,
                                                                           boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, model.toString());
                                                viewHolder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .centerCrop()
                                        .into(viewHolder.child_view);

                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Don't spam with irrelevant tags. also show your adapter code

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be clearing the image anywhere when you bind the viewholder. You also aren't using any kind of placeholder with Glide, so Glide won't do anything to the `ImageView` except when it successfully loads an image. When the viewholder is recycled, any existing image will be there until a new one replaces it.

Try using `.placeHolder(null)` with your Glide builder code, or remove the existing image by calling `viewHolder.child_view.setImageDrawable(null)` before loading with Glide.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Glide.with(mContext).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15416659)